# How to get type from json data and filter / swap the info

Tags: jquery

JSON

```
{
    "details": [
    {
      "name": "A",
      "title": "B",
      "description": "Cat cat",
      "link": "http://www.google.com/",
      "type": "hi, may, meow"
    }
    ]
  }
```

JQuery

```
 $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'to/path/details.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){

          var type = response[0].type;
          var pairs = window.location.search.split("&");
          var lastWord = pairs[pairs.length-1].split("=")[1];
          if(type === lastWord){
            $('#accordion').filter(lastWord);
            $('#accordion').html(response);
          }

        },
        error: function(response) {
          $("#accordion").css("display","none");
          alert("Error occured because of no data");
        }

      });
```

HTML

```
<div id="accordion">
  <h1 class="name">{{name}}<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></h1>
<div class="accordion-content row">
  <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 profile">
    <a href="#">{{link}}</a>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12 profile-body">
    <p>
      {{description}}
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

HTML is done via SWIG - I think could use data to pass variables to {{name}}, {{description}} for example. But not sure about swig itself.

Back to the issue:

1. Tried to get type from json. 
   `response[0].type` returns message: "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined". Why response[0].type is returning the error?
2. If url word matches with type from json, it will filter by lastWord and append all details by repeating accordion areas via loop in swig. Or could append like this: "`<div id="accordion">stuff</div>`" in `$.ajax`. 
   How to filter accurately by lastWord and append/change all the details every time click on link?

**Updated**

```
   $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'path/to/details.json',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(response){

          var type = response.details[0].type;

          var pairs = window.location.search.split("&");
          var lastWord = pairs[pairs.length-1].split("=")[1];

            if(type == lastWord){
              alert('yay');
              $('#accordion').filter(lastWord);
              var output='<h1 class="name">' + response.details[0].name + '<i class="fa fa-chevron-down"></i></h1>';
                  output+='<div class="accordion-content row"><div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-12 profile"><a href="#">' + response.details[0].link+"</a></div>";
                  output+='<div class="col-lg-9 col-sm-12 profile-body"><p>' + response.details[0].description + '</p></div></div>';
             }

        },
        error: function(response) {
          $("#accordion").css("display","none");
          alert("Error occured because of no data");
        }

      });
```

HTML filter link - if click on specific link, it will need to match with word in type then append the details in accordion accordingly

```
<div class="filterexample">
  <a href="?type=all">View All</a>
  <a href="?type=hi">hi</a>
  <a href="?type=meow">meow</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is an object, thus `response[0]` has not meaning.  It looks like you should be using

```
var type = response.details[0].type;
```

You are not showing your "append details" logic in your question, so I am not sure how to answer your second part.  You will have problems matching something like `hi, may, meow` against a portion of a query string, as assumedly the data in query string would be URL-encoded.  Your solution is also fragile in assuming that the type value in query string is always in last position.  You should look to deserialize the entire query strong and look for the particular parameter you are trying to match.

Comment: thanks. Have updated code above as in append and filter links. I have realized that there may be more than 1 word in json type. I am still not sure how but trying to figure it out